# Add multiple columns in select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Scenario is like:

SomeTable { A int, B int, C int }

I need to select and add with formula: A + 25%B + 50%C. If in decimal, round upto next full digit and display an asterisk and a spcae preciding the sum. Each column needs to be rounded off before adding.

Suppose data is

10 16 12
 
14 15 19

Select should return: 20, 28 *.

I am thinking of using case statements but its getting very dirty with that. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this in your database instead of extracting the values and then performing the mathematical operations on them in the application that is using the data?

Comment: I am using this select in a stored procedure. The SP is linked to SSRS report. Point is that if there are any minor changes the reports need not be deployed again. A simple change in stored proc would get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE is your only way:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (A int, B int, C int)
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (10, 16, 12 )
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (14, 15, 19 )
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN ROUND(A+.25*B+C*.5,0)<A+.25*B+C*.5 THEN
            CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(int,ROUND(A+.25*B+C*.5,0))+1)+' *' 
        ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(int,ROUND(A+.25*B+C*.5,0))) 
    END
    FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
------------
20
28 *

(2 row(s) affected)
```